# MySQL search comma separated keywords

Tags: mysql, php

I have keywords column in my table and there are comma (,) separated values. example: hello, world

I have search engine with same codes:

```
$search = $_GET ['search'];

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM table WHERE keywords LIKE ?");
$query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE keywords LIKE ? LIMIT $start , $limit");
$sql->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
```

When I type only 'hello' or only 'world' in my search bar, there is result, but if I type both words together, like 'Hello world' there is no result.

**EDIT:**
I edited my codes for FULL TEXT SEARCH

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM table WHERE MATCH (id,keywords) AGAINST ('$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
$query->execute();
```

and

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (id,keywords) AGAINST ('$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT $start , $limit");
$sql->execute();
```

It works better, but now I get some irrelevant results. Is there any way to filter results and order they relevance?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you must keep `keywords` as a CSV, you can use `FIND_IN_SET()`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num 
FROM table 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('hello', keywords) 
AND FIND_IN_SET('world', keywords);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try [FullText](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) index and [match...against](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) queries.

As suggested by [jkavalik](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/64556/jkavalik):

You can do `ORDER BY MATCH (id,keywords) AGAINST ('$search' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) desc` to get the most relevant on top.

But what you *should* do is: create another table `keywords` with a *Foreign key* to the original table and store each keyword on a separate row, not in a comma separated list. Such lists will only give you headaches later.